# Should I prune my Crassula rogersii?

Tags: pruning, succulents, branches, fleshy-leaves

I have what I think is a little *Crassula rogersii* that's been growing out in three branches from a little trunk. The branch in the middle seems to be getting somewhat top-heavy (you can see how this middle branch is upright in the 1st photo which was taken yesterday, but it's leaning way over to the side in the second photo, which I took today).

Should I prune this plant? If so, how? I love that it's been growing like a little tree, and I'd love to see it grow more branches like the three it has now.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prune your succulent it will form new branches. If you leave it alone those branches will get thicker and develop a woody stem. So it is a matter of do you want to? neither will hurt the plant. If you want it to have more branches trim it if not leave it alone. Just make sure to leave some leaves behind.